# Составить составное ограничение для Postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть три поля в таблице:

```
approver: String
deleted: Boolean
user_id: Integer
```

Надо составить исключение для таблицы на событие добавления. Нельзя допускачть что бы были записи с одинаковыми user_id, deleted = false, approver - не пустой.

Т.е. такие ситуации допустимы:

```
approver: "Any1", deleted: true, user_id: 1
approver: "Any2", deleted: true, user_id: 1
approver: "Any3", deleted: false, user_id: 1
```

А вот такие нет:

```
approver: "Any1", deleted: true, user_id: 1
approver: "Any2", deleted: false, user_id: 1
approver: "Any3", deleted: false, user_id: 1
```

Как написать такое ограничение для Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен частичный (`partial`) уникальный индекс:

```
сreate unique index on tablename using btree ( user_id ) 
where not deleted and approver is not null;
```

Такой частичный уникальный индекс накладывает ограничение уникальности только на те строки, которые удовлетворяют условию `where`.

PS: возможно я неверное интерпретировал что вы подразумевали под "approver - не пустой"

Answer (score 1):

1) В объявлении колонок указать для полей NOT NULL(недопустимо отсутствие значения), например так:

```
create table accounts(
    approver VARCHAR(25) not null,
    deleted  boolean NOT NULL,
    user_id  integer NOT NULL
);
```

2) объявить триггер на вставку записей, в котором и будет происходить проверка условия

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_accounts_bi
    BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.deleted = false)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_unique_accounts();
```

3) триггерная функция

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_unique_accounts (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
  -- проверка: если такой действующий уже есть, то...
  if exists(select 1 from accounts where deleted = false and user_id=new.user_id)
  then 
    RETURN NULL; /* МОЖНО промолчать и ничего не добавить */
  -- RAISE EXCEPTION 'Действующий пользователь user_id=% уже существует', new.user_id; /* ИЛИ вызвать исключение */
  else 
    RETURN NEW;
  end if;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на наличие race condition в этом решении. По причине присутствия которого уникальность может наблюдаться, но не гарантируется (кроме разве что serializable изоляции). Ну и фактическая неточность: вы пропустили аналогичный триггер на before insert.